# scala properly defining a empty value for a abstract data type

Tags: scala, generics, abstract-syntax-tree, covariance, abstract-data-type

I have a ADT as follows:

```
sealed trait Tree[A]
case object EmptyTree extends Tree[Nothing]
case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]
case class Node[A](op: Seq[A] => A, branches: Tree[A]*) extends Tree[A]
```

When i try to build a function to randomly create Trees i get a problem with the EmptyTree, the type system does not let go through

```
  def create(acc: Tree[A], currentDepth: Int): Tree[A] = currentDepth match {
    case maxDepth => Leaf(terminalSet(r.nextInt(terminalSet.length)))
    case 0 => {
      val op_pos = r.nextInt(fSetLength)
      val branches: Seq[Tree[A]] = for (i <- 0 to r.nextInt(fSetLength)) yield create(EmptyTree, currentDepth+1)
      Node(functionSet(op_pos)._1, branches:_*)
    }
    case _ => {
      if (r.nextFloat() <= probF) {
        val op_pos = r.nextInt(fSetLength)
        val branches = for (i <- 0 to r.nextInt(fSetLength)) yield create(EmptyTree, currentDepth + 1)
        Node(functionSet(op_pos)._1, branches:_*)
      }
      else
        Leaf(terminalSet(r.nextInt(terminalSet.length)))
    }
  }
  create(EmptyTree, 0)
```

basically in `create(EmptyTree, currentDepth + 1)` it complains that it is expecting a `Tree[A]` and is receiving a `EmptyTree.type`

Comment: I updated my answer: I think you should keep your `Tree` trait invariant

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler objections are justified. The compiler expects `Tree[A]` and you are passing `EmptyTree`, whose super type is `Tree[Nothing]`. A priori, there's no subtyping relationship between these two types.

What you want is `Tree` to be *covariant*: if `X <: Y` then `Tree[X] <: Tree[Y]`. Then, as `Nothing <: A` for *any* `A` you get `EmptyTree.type <: Tree[A]` and you can always pass `EmptyTree` whenever you need a `Tree[A]`.

The *syntax* for declaring the `A` parameter in `Tree` covariant is `Tree[+A]`; change that and your code should compile.

This is a good post on covariance and contravariance in Scala: [Be friend with covariance and contravariance](http://julien.richard-foy.fr/blog/2013/02/21/be-friend-with-covariance-and-contravariance/)

**UPDATE** After your [questioning answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41185885/614394) I have actually looked at your constructors for `Tree` and, as defined, you **cannot** make `Tree` covariant. Sadly, the compiler won't complain (you see, it should actually complain *more*). Your `op` in `Node` is contravariant on `Seq[A]`, and thus you cannot make `Node` covariant. At this point you might be thinking:

> Who cares about `Node`? I just want `Tree` to be covariant!

*Well*, through making its supertype `Tree` covariant Node becomes so in practice. `scalac` should actually check that all sub type constructors of a covariant one are (or could be made) covariant. Anyway, code showing this follows:

```
// you need a value for EmptyTree! thus default
def evaluateTree[Z](tree: Tree[Z], default: Z): Z =
  tree match {
    case EmptyTree    => default
    case Leaf(value)  => value
    // note how you need to essentially cast here
    case Node(op: (Seq[Z] => Z), args @ _*) =>
      op(args map { branches => evaluateTree(branches, default) })
  }

trait A
trait B extends A

val notNice: Tree[A] = Node[B]({ bs: Seq[B] => bs.head }, EmptyTree)
// ClassCastException!
val uhoh = evaluateTree(notNice, new A {})
```

**UPDATE 2** Back to your original question :) I'd leave your `Tree` type invariant, and have an `EmptyTree[A]()` case class; it is a pity that there are no parameterless value classes.

```
sealed trait Tree[A]
case class EmptyTree[A]() extends Tree[A]
case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]
// I wouldn't use varargs here, make a method for that if you want
case class Node[A](op: Seq[A] => A, branches: Tree[A]*) extends Tree[A]
// for convenience, it could be inside `Tree` companion
def emptyTree[A]: EmptyTree[A] = EmptyTree()

def evaluateTree[Z](tree: Tree[Z], default: Z): Z =
  tree match {
    case EmptyTree() =>
      default
    case Leaf(value) =>
      value
    // no need to match generic types or anything here
    case Node(op, args @ _*) =>
      op(args map { branches => evaluateTree(branches, default) })
  }

trait A
trait B extends A

// doesn't work now
// val notNice: Tree[A] = Node[B]({ bs: Seq[B] => bs.head }, emptyTree)
val notNice: Tree[B] = Node[B]({ bs: Seq[B] => bs.head }, emptyTree)

// doesn't compile, no class cast exception
// val uhoh = evaluateTree(notNice, new A {})
```

Comment: i finally understood it. I also needed to match generic types! Thank you very much

Btw when you say `// I wouldn't use varargs here, make a method for that if you want`. Which method? It was the only way i found to have a tree with an arbitrary number of branches